SSRS does not populate data in every second page column
I need to generate report with 4 columns like newspaper and I am expecting to get the next result:

but SSRS skips populating every second column:

On the next pages the same result (The first row is populated in Page header).
If I set count columns 3 I have got the same result.
The first page:

The second page:

Please help to fix this issue.
I am trying to find any solution to fix it but I didn't meet anything like my issue. Solutions with matrix cannot be used because I don't know how many rows will be in every group.
With the single column data the data is not populated on every second page - it looks it is not related with multi-column.
I have tried to use a textbox with big text - the same result: the second column (or the second page for single column) is skipped.
